# Memtest86 freezing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, memtest

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 several months ago I noticed that my computer is running more slowly than before. It takes anywhere from 30 seconds to one minute to launch Chrome browser. Pages load more slowly. Other programs function more slowly. So I ran memtest86 from a restart, and it froze. I have attached a photo of the memtest screen but I don't have the technical expertise to understand the data. Please note the Test at 60% with the hash marks: it has been stuck at 60% for the last ten minutes and nothing else on the screen has changed since then. Please advise as to what I need to do to determine whether I have a problem with memory or other hardware, or if there is a firmware issue, etc. Thank you.
[image: Memtest86 at 12:49 on May 13, 2021]

Comment: Boot your machine and show me `free -h` and `sudo swapon -s` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: To be completely sure about your RAM sticks please run memtest from older LiveCDs like Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. On my C2Ds with non-faulty hardware it runs well.

Comment: I haven't seen your response to my request for more data...

Answer (score 2):

If memtest freezes, you very likely have a hardware problem. It's probably your RAM, but there is no way to be sure.

If you did any overclocking, the first thing to try is to reset that to normal. Similar with RAM timings: If you changed those, reverting them to factory defaults in the BIOS would be worth a try.

If you are sure you did none of that, it's time to replace the RAM. According to the memtest output, you seem to have a single bank of RAM, right? If it's more than one, you could try to remove part of the RAM (make sure the lower RAM banks are filled) and re-check; you might get lucky and find out which of the RAM modules is affected.

But first check if you maybe have an thermal problem: Check the temperature inside the PC case. Open it to see if all fans are spinning. Clean out the dust puppies (very carefully with a vacuum cleaner and if you have it, with compressed air in a can; or with a photo "rocket blower" if you have one).

HTH

Comment: I am not sure how many RAM banks I have. Here is a link to a photo I shot last week of the inside of my computer's case: https://www.4shared.com/s/fRSJ14krdea . Can you advise whether I have one or two RAM banks? And if two, which one is the "lower RAM bank"? Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be only one alright. It's that small circuit board standing upright near the power supply / hard disk, next to that bunch of brown cables. The little white plastic lever on its left side will unlock it. But it might be a bit difficult to get it out with that  metal box in the lower right corner in the way. Check your PC's manual what type of RAM you need.

Comment: If your PC works normally for a while (20-30 min) when you first switch it on and after that starts getting slower and eventually halts / crashes, this would indicate a thermal problem. Check if the fans are spinning and if there is air flow near them. There is one in the power supply unit (the hamster cage on the bottom left), and probably one more in that black plastic duct on the top right.

Comment: Thanks, HuHa. The computer doesn't worsen after 30 minutes, and I can hear the fans running constantly with good air flow, so I don't think it's thermal. I suspect it's the RAM gone bad, so I'm trying to source a replacement. Actually, HP's chat agent said I can install two 8GB DDR4 RAM sticks, so I am trying to confirm those will fit in the slots before purchasing on Amazon. Do you recommend a different/better vendor? Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: Per HuHa's suggestion, I removed two of the four RAM sticks and am rerunning memtest86. With those two pulled out, memtest is now running properly through a whole gamut of tests. The fact that it is running indicates that at least one of the two sticks I removed is bad, so I plan to replace it. And for good measure, I'll probably replace all four so that my machine is running four identical sticks. Unless someone here can advise as to why that's not advised. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, can anyone advise as to the compatibility of installing DDR4 sticks instead of DDR3? I understand that DDR4 was developed after my computer was created, so DDR4 simply wasn't available back then. I don't understand the technical difference between the two, so any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: No! Newest Memtest is a big single bug by itself. Testing the same memory using 12.04 LTS livecd always runs well, without any red messages.

Comment: @ScottSemel You can't mix/match DDR3 and DDR4 DIMMS. You must use the style that your motherboard supports.

Comment: @N0rbert Please explain. What have you noticed with newer memtests?

Comment: @heynnema Newer memtest versions stall on absolutely non-fault older hardware like Lenovo SL500 (C2D, DDR2) or VAIO VPCF1 (i7 first generation, DDR3).

Comment: @N0rbert Tell me that you're running on newer hardware than that :-) Are you **sure** that there's really not a RAM problem on those case examples? `memtest` freezing is normally an indication that there's a RAM problem. Was this when using AMD processors? AMD processors are **very fussy** about RAM compatibility.

Comment: In my case C2D = Intel Core 2 Duo [T9550, 2008](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37130/intel-core-2-duo-processor-t9550-6m-cache-2-66-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html) with 8 Gb of DDR2, i7 = Intel [i7-740qm, 2010](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/49024/intel-core-i7-740qm-processor-6m-cache-1-73-ghz.html) with 16 Gb DDR3. Running 18.04 LTS and testing 21.04. So I'm sure. I do not have any AMD. And if I remember correctly UX32A with i7-3537u, 2013 and 10 Gb of DDR3 also stalls in memtest.

Comment: @N0rbert Someday... when you have the time... it would be interesting to pick one of those machines and try removing some RAM, and see if `memtest` runs with only one inserted. If it does, then SWAP in the other DIMM/SODIMM and rerun `memtest`.

Comment: @heynnema: How do I determine whether my motherboard supports DDR4?

Comment: Check the manual. If you don't have one, try to find it online. If you can't find the exact board type on the circuit board, watch the first boot messages or in the BIOS.

Comment: @ScottSemel Start by answering my questions from 19 hours ago...

Comment: @heynnema: I am not sure which questions from 19 hours ago you are referring to. I don't have a lot of technical background under the hood of a computer, which is why I am on this forum asking the best questions I know how to ask. I called HP this afternoon and they told me that my computer does not support DDR4, so I will have to use DDR3 RAM sticks running no faster than 1333MHz. I'll also use memtest86 instead of memtest86+ to see if I get a different result. My HP is a Compaq 6000 Pro SFF, which I bought about 10 years ago.

Comment: Update: I installed four new 4GB RAM sticks in my computer and the machine seems to be running fine, though running memtest86+ at start-up did not work. This time it froze at "Test 31%". Not sure if I have a bad RAM slot, but everything seems to be running smoothly. Not sure what else to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug on memtest86: [bug #1876157](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1876157)
I ran into the same problem, and memtest86 hung at exactly the same place on ubuntu 21.04.  I ran "memtester 6650M" on 8 Gig system to mostly test memory.  It ran 5 cycles with no errors.  The 6650M left just enough room for the O/S.